# Font size in pt (pgfplots)

Tags: fonts, pgfplots, texstudio

how can I set the font size in pt in pgfplots?
Reduced to the basics, my document looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
width=1\textwidth,
height=0.6\textwidth,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
label style={font=\large},      
]       
    \addplot [line width=1pt]  table   [x=TLE, y=Cute]{bstern.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

I am including the produced pdf in an other document with 0.8/textwidth. As I want a consistent font size, I want to set the label font size to 15pt.

Is there any package I can include, so that I have a more variety aside of \small, \large etc.?

Comment: I think you are bettwe suited if you include it in the main document. May be adding the `external` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
compat=newest,
width=1\textwidth,
height=0.6\textwidth,
}
 \newcommand\mtlarge{\fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[
label style={font=\mtlarge},      
]       
   \addplot [line width=1pt]  table   [x=TLE, y=Cute]{bstern.txt};

 \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you explain me why you set two font sizes and not just one?

Comment: @wheeler The first argument to `\fontsize` is the font size proper, the second argument is the baselineskip.